# Error while opening in write binary mode in module installation

Tags: 7

I wanted to install a module for SSL, but when I go to "install new module" and enter the .tar.gz file and click install this error appears:

Error while opening {temporary://update-extraction-6f1a1322/securelogin/securelogin.info} in write binary mode

I don't know why and I didn't find any thing over the net.
please help me
thanks a milion :)

Comment: did you try installing by uploading the files through ftp?

Comment: thanx it works :-------------------------